# Configuring roaming profiles

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, active-directory, roaming-profile

Running a DC (Windows Server 2008 R2) with Windows 7 Clients.

I have configured the roaming profiles (I believe), however once while logging in, the account logs in with a TEMP profile.

Can someone clarify the correct configuration for roaming profiles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**How did you setup the profile in the first place??**
Very Very important information. Otherwise, we have to ask, "Did you turn on the DC?" :)

To create a roaming profile:
Open Active Directory Users and Computers and connect to the Domain Controller. Or just login to the DC itself and open the AD Users and Computer

1. Right-click the user account and then choose Properties => Profiles.
2. Type the path into Profile path, like `\\Server\Share\User's
   Romaning profile folder`
3. Make sure the share is accessible to that User also.

You can also get a log of the User's login and see where it breaks.

Look under their registry: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon`.

Make an Reg_DWORD called **UserEnvDebugLevel** and set it to HEX 0x30002.

Comment: How would I go about having two different OS's?  For example I have machines using Windows 7 and others on XP?

Comment: @Joe: That is a whole nother question that needs to be posted as such. Short Answer is: It depends on your configuration.

Comment: Nevermind, I've found how to do so... For some reason I forgot to change the security when I originally done it.

Thanks for this.

Comment: Anytime.  Did you ever post your other question?

Comment: Yes, I posted it on Server Fault.  Someone replied how, please feel free to add as the folder is still left locally  but is empty.